# Unable to configure ORC properties in Spark

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hive, cloudera

I am using Spark 1.6 (Cloudera 5.8.2) and tried below methods to configure ORC properties. But it does not effect output.

Below is the code snippet i tried.

```
 DataFrame dataframe =
                hiveContext.createDataFrame(rowData, schema);
dataframe.write().format("orc").options(new HashMap(){
            {

                put("orc.compress","SNAPPY");
                put("hive.exec.orc.default.compress","SNAPPY");

                put("orc.compress.size","524288");
                put("hive.exec.orc.default.buffer.size","524288");


                put("hive.exec.orc.compression.strategy", "COMPRESSION");

            }
        }).save("spark_orc_output");
```

Apart from this, i tried these properties set in hive-site.xml and hiveContext object also.

hive --orcfiledump on output confirms that the configurations not applied. Orcfiledump snippet is below.

```
Compression: ZLIB
Compression size: 262144
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are making two different errors here. I don't blame you; I've been there...

**Issue #1**
`orc.compress` and the rest are not Spark `DataFrameWriter` options. They are Hive configuration properties, that must be defined *before* creating the `hiveContext` object...

- either in the `hive-site.xml` available to Spark at launch time
- or in your code, by re-creating the `SparkContext`...

`sc.getConf.get("orc.compress","<undefined>")  // depends on Hadoop conf`
 `sc.stop`
 `val scAlt = new org.apache.spark.SparkContext((new org.apache.spark.SparkConf).set("orc.compress","snappy"))`
 `scAlt.getConf.get("orc.compress","<undefined>") // will now be Snappy`
 `val hiveContextAlt = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(scAlt)`

*[Edit] with Spark 2.x the script would become...*
 `spark.sparkContext.getConf.get("orc.compress","<undefined>")  // depends on Hadoop conf`
 `spark.close`
 `val sparkAlt = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.builder().config("orc.compress","snappy").getOrCreate()`
 `sparkAlt.sparkContext.getConf.get("orc.compress","<undefined>") // will now be Snappy`

**Issue #2**
Spark uses its own SerDe libraries for ORC (and Parquet, JSON, CSV, etc) so it does not have to honor the standard Hadoop/Hive properties.

There are some Spark-specific properties for Parquet, and they are [well documented](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#configuration). But again, these properties must be set *before* creating (or re-creating) the `hiveContext`.

For ORC and the other formats, you have to resort to format-specific `DataFrameWriter` options; quoting the latest [JavaDoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.html)...

> You can set the following ORC-specific option(s) for writing ORC
>   files:
>   • `compression` (default `snappy`): compression codec to use when
>   saving to file. This can be one of the known case-insensitive shorten
>   names (`none`, `snappy`, `zlib`, and `lzo`). This will override `orc.compress`

*Note that the default compression codec has changed with Spark 2; before that it was `zlib`*

So the only thing you can set is the compression codec, using

```
dataframe.write().format("orc").option("compression","snappy").save("wtf")
```

Comment: I tried below code . It did not change compression from zlib to snappy. SparkConf sc = new SparkConf();
 sc.set("orc.compress","snappy");
 sc.set("orc.compress.size", "524288");
 sc.setAppName("test_orc_config");
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sc);
.....
 HiveContext hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(jsc.sc());
 DataFrame df =hiveContext.createDataFrame(rowData, schema);
 df.write().format("orc").option("compression","snappy").save("spark_orc_output");

Comment: i tried configuring hive-site.xml . It did not work.

Comment: So your last option is the easiest one: `***.option("compression","snappy").***`