# How to set a config parameter to a specific value in the interactive shell (Spark 2.0.1)

Tags: scala, shell, apache-spark

I want to set a config parameter to a specific value *in the interactive shell* (Spark 2.0.1). I know that I can set this parameter when invoking the spark-shell. For example:

```
] $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --master local[4] --conf spark.es.resource="myindex/mytype"
```

What I want instead is to set this value inside the shell. The command:

```
scala> spark.conf.set("spark.es.resource","myindex/mytype")
```

does not seem to set the *real* parameter spark.es.resource because subsequent call to spark.read.format (that makes use of the resource value) crashes. It works if I set the parameter outside the shell.

Comment: As explained in the documentation, the `SparkConf` object returned by the `conf()` method is a **clone** of the current configuration. You need to stop then recreate your `spark` object with a different configuration, and under a different name to avoid side effects. Cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41756775/unable-to-configure-orc-properties-in-spark/41766865#41766865

Comment: The problem is that I want ultimately to set this parameter in a function. My first idea was to pass spark session as a parameter to that function and set there the value I want. When I try spark.stop() inside a fct, I get the result: value stop is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.Builder

Comment: Ah, yes, new major version of Spark, new API, breaking changes... I just updated my post in the link above, to show both the 1.6 and the 2.0 syntax.

Comment: Sorry, error: value close is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.Builder

Comment: Right, Spark 2.1.0 supports both `spark.close` and `spark.stop` (http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession) but Spark 2.0.2 supports only `spark.stop`

Comment: But anyway the `spark` object is expected to be a **SparkSession**, not a **SparkSession.Builder** > so you did not apply the `.getOrCreate()` method to start the context?!? No need to stop it then!

Comment: That's strange. As soon as I enter in the shell, I call my function with spark as only parameter (type is SparkSession) and at the first line of fct(), I spark.stop and I get this error about SparkSession.builder.