# How to set ORC stripe size in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, orc

I am trying to generate a dataset in Spark(2.3) and write it in ORC file format.
I'm trying to set some properties for ORC stripe size and compress size. I took hints from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41756775/unable-to-configure-orc-properties-in-spark) SO post. But spark is not honoring those properties and my stripe size in the resulting ORC files is much lower than what I've set.

```
val conf: SparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("App")
  .set("spark.sql.orc.impl", "native")
  .set("spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreOrc", "true")
  .set("spark.sql.orc.stripe.size", "67108864")
  .set("spark.sql.orc.compress.size", "262144")
  .set("orc.stripe.size", "67108864")
  .set("orc.compress.size", "262144")

data.sortWithinPartitions("column")
  .write
  .option("orc.compress", "ZLIB")
  .mode("overwrite")
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc")
  .save(outputPath)
```

I also tried to write the data as:

```
data.sortWithinPartitions("column")
  .write
  .option("orc.compress", "ZLIB")
  .option("orc.stripe.size", "67108864")
  .option("orc.compress.size", "262144")
  .mode("overwrite")
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc")
  .save(outputPath)
```

But no luck.

Relevant sections from ORC file dump:

```
File Version: 0.12 with ORC_135
Rows: 3174228
Compression: ZLIB
Compression size: 32768
...
Stripe: offset: 3 data: 6601333 rows: 30720 tail: 2296 index: 16641
Stripe: offset: 6620273 data: 6016778 rows: 25600 tail: 2279 index: 13595
Stripe: offset: 12652925 data: 6031290 rows: 25600 tail: 2284 index: 13891
Stripe: offset: 18700390 data: 6132228 rows: 25600 tail: 2283 index: 13805
Stripe: offset: 24848706 data: 6066176 rows: 25600 tail: 2267 index: 13855
Stripe: offset: 30931004 data: 6562819 rows: 30720 tail: 2308 index: 16851
Stripe: offset: 37512982 data: 6462380 rows: 30720 tail: 2304 index: 16994
Stripe: offset: 43994660 data: 6655346 rows: 30720 tail: 2291 index: 17031
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works on Spark 2.4.4.

```
spark = (SparkSession
     .builder
     .config('hive.exec.orc.default.stripe.size', 64*1024*1024)
     .getOrCreate()
     )
df = ...
df.write.format('orc').save('output.orc')
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue and in my case it appears to pertain to the version of Hortonworks HDP used. In this post you can see a similar discussion, where they suggest using HDP 2.6.3+ with Spark 2.2+, that utilizes the newer Hive libraries:

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/159893/spark-orc-stripe-size.html

Perhaps your Spark 2.3 is still configured to use the older Hive 1.2.1 library.