# How to define ORC stripe size with Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata, orc, trino

I am submitting Spark jobs to an EMR Cluster to process files, writing later then as ORC files that will be read by Presto.

Analyzing thous files, I found a problem that the size of the stripes are being written with a lot less rows then I expected by each stripe.

I know that in Hive I can set the stripe size of a table, but is there a way to do it in Spark also?

Comment: Just to make clear -- you mean  Presto DB or Presto SQL (now called Trino)?

Comment: The same question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52075481/2700344 - please check does it help or not

Comment: @Piotr Yes it is Trino!

Comment: @leftjoin do you now if it is possible to define the row count of the stripe directly, or just the size? btw, it is not working the setting that is in the link you mentioned

Comment: In Trino stripe size is controlled with `hive.orc.writer.stripe-min-size` and `hive.orc.writer.stripe-max-size` configuration properties, but I do not know about Spark.